# Bind values to search String into table column

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to implement a search functionality into table column using this code:

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT * " +
            "FROM ACTIVE_PAIRS ap " +
            "WHERE ap.pair iLIKE CONCAT('%', ?1, '%') " +
            "LIMIT ?2 " +
            "OFFSET ?3"
    )
    Flux<ActivePairsFullDTO> findAllBySearchParam(String params,  long limit,  long offset);
```

But I get error: Binding parameters is not supported for the statement

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little surprised that you are getting this error, because I would have thought the first error you should get is that your statement is not valid JPQL, nor HQL since `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` aren't part of JPQL.

In order to use SQL you need to specify [`nativeQuery=true`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html#nativeQuery--) in the annotation.

Since you also return a `Flux` I'm not sure you use Spring Data JPA as tagged, but Spring Data R2DBC?

Either way, the exception you are seeing stems from the fact that some databases don't accept bind variables for `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.

For Spring Data JPA you can work around this by simply removing those clauses and add a `PageRequest` argument to the method.

This approach is not supported for Spring Data R2DBC. Instead you would use [SpEL expressions to include the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` values](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/276#issuecomment-574839100).